# How to I get a <textarea> value on the fly using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to retrieve and process a `<textarea>` content and process it on the fly. For example:

```
<textarea id='a'></textarea>
<textarea id='b'></textarea>
<script>
    $('#a').keypress(function() {
        $('#b').text(this.value);
    });

</script>
```

The problem with this is that it seems that the event fires before the element value changes. Thus, I'm always one character behind.

Is there a way to get the value as it changes?

Comment: Have you tried `keyup()`?

Comment: I tried it based on Rahul Tripathi's answer and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `keyup` like this:-

```
<textarea id='a'></textarea>
<textarea id='b'></textarea>
<script>
    $('#a').keyup(function() {
        $('#b').text(this.value);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of jQuery:  http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

> The keyup event is sent to an element when the user releases a key on the keyboard.

```
<textarea id='a'></textarea>
<textarea id='b'></textarea>
<script>
    $('#a').keyup(function() {
        $('#b').text(this.value);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try .Change() event

```
<script>
    $('#a').Change(function() {
        $('#b').text(this.value);
});

</script>
```